# How to avoid losing the virtual fields after failing validation?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a model with two virtual fields `full_name` and `avatar`, `avatar` is the full path to the user avatar.

In the edit form I print the avatar picture but when I send the form and validation fails the virtual fields are lost because the model is not loaded and uses the `$this->request->data` information.

Is there any way to load the virtual fields without sending it in hidden fields?

Comment: Is this an avatar solely for one user or is this model for multiple users? If you only have one user, I would say you could try using `$_SESSION` because this is hardly sensitive data, but obviously this would not work if you're displaying multiple users with their avatars. And if the latter is the case, why are you making these fields virtual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the virtual fields as hidden fields in the form.